# Jquery Calculator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem on how to reveal my results using jquery. Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deanilvincent/ou5a1kku/). It doesn't run properly. Please help me to fix it.

What I want is whenever I click calculate, the result of the calculation from the function will show at the result span.

Here's my html and javascript tags if you want to see:

```
        <input type="text" id="loan_amount" placeholder="Loan Amount"><br />
        <input type="text" id="interest_rate" placeholder="Interest Rate"><br />
        <input type="text" id="payments_per_year" placeholder="Payments Per Year"><br />
        <input type="text" id="years" placeholder="Years"><br />
        <input type="text" id="payment" placeholder="Payment"><br />
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Calculate">
        <span class="results"></span>
```

And here's my javascript/jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function(){
            var loan_amount = $("#loan_amount").val();
            var interest_rate = $("#interest_rate").val();
            var payments_per_year = $("#payments_per_year").val();
            var years = $("#years").val();
            var payment = $("#payment").val();


            function computeSchedule(loan_amount, interest_rate, payments_per_year, years, payment) {
                var schedule = [];
                var remaining = loan_amount;
                var number_of_payments = payments_per_year * years;

                    for (var i=0; i<=number_of_payments; i++) {
                        var interest = remaining * (interest_rate/100/payments_per_year);
                        var principle = (payment-interest);
                        var row = [i, principle>0?principle:0, interest>0?interest:0, remaining>0?remaining:0];
                        schedule.push(row);
                        remaining -= principle
                    }

                return schedule;
            }
        }); 
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling the `computeSchedule` function. There is also nothing in your code that will do "the result of the calculation from the function will show at the result span"

Comment: sir @rikitikitik I updated my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/deanilvincent/ou5a1kku/2/ Please help me to do like this https://www.easycalculation.com/mortgage/amortization.php

Comment: You should update the code above, as well as the jsFiddle link. Your code works as you wrote it. Your function returns an array and the span displays the array. As for the link of what you want to happen, you should summarize that in your question above instead of asking users to go to a site that may or may not be safe, and may be taken offline anytime.

Comment: @truelogicINC, What is your question / problem? "doesn't run properly" and "like this other site" isn't very specific